# DataStore: Exception: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I am getting the error as per the heading and am totally at a lose as to why.

```
public static int addSkill( String code ) {
    PreparedStatement insertSkill = null;
    int result = 0;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = database.connect(null, null);
        insertSkill = connection.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (0,?)" );
        /* *Set the wild cards of the prepared statement insertSkill */
        insertSkill.setString( 1, code );
        result = insertSkill.executeUpdate();
    } // try()
    catch ( java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException insert ) {
        // This catches a problem of inserting a duplicate skill.
        // If it occurs, the method will return 0 (initial value of result).
        log.errorMessage("DataStore: Exception: " + insert.getMessage());
    } // catch()
    catch ( SQLException sqlException ) {
        log.errorMessage("DataStore: Exception: " + sqlException.getMessage());
    } // catch()
    finally{
        if(connection !=null){
            try {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                log.errorMessage("Connction failed to return to the pool\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}// addSkill()
```

Comment: You should include your error or what should be the expecting behavior and what you're getting on your posts for better clarification.

Comment: btw, are you suppose to pass null value as your database.connect parameter? I have never used mysql with java but I think you are suppose to forward your username and password here!

Comment: how many columns does this table have? Try INSERT INTO Skill (columnName, columnName,) VALUES (0,?)